# Is there a way I can avoid getting another copy of a child data when I include a parent in EF5?

Tags: c#, json, linq, entity-framework, serialization

I have the following classes and I am having a problem with getting data from them:

```
public partial class Exam    {
    public Exam()
    {
        this.Objectives = new List<Objective>();
    }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }
}

public partial class Objective    {
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting a list of Objectives and I want to include Exam.Name.

Here is the query that I created so I could get Exam which would give me a way to get the Exam name.

```
    public IList<Objective> GetObjectives(int examId)
    {
        var objectives = _objectivesRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Include(o => o.Exam)
            .ToList();
        return objectives;
    }
```

Here is the mapping that I am using:

```
    public ObjectiveMap()
    {
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Exam)
            .WithMany(t => t.Objectives)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ExamId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Unfortunately this small query returns over 6MB of data. When I check with Fiddler I see:

> Objective objects > Exam objects > **Objective objects**

What I need to have is:

> Objective objects > Exam objects

Is there a solution for this. How can I stop EF5 from getting another layer of objectives?

Comment: Have you disabled lazy loading?

Comment: Yes I have: DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: I think you are not getting a new copy but it's referring to the same object  again. There is only one instance.

Comment: As far as I can see with the Fiddler JSON view I am getting a list of Objectives each with an exam. When I look into the contents of that exam I see many objective objects inside it.

Comment: i guess the .Include(o=>o.Exam ) causes the whole exam to load

Comment: Using DTOs here is better for two reasons: you have 100% control over their contents and you decouple the DAL from the service interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSOn serialization is a different issue. Not related to entity framework here. You can use `ScriptIgnore` attribute to avoid serializing it,

```
public partial class Exam    {
 //....
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }
}
```